# Python string doesn't change, appends to array

Tags: python

i'm going to find longest word in string, so when i write something like:

```
longestWord = {'value': '', 'len': 0}
for word in words:
    if len(word) > longestWord['len']:
        longestWord['value'] = word
        longestWord['len'] = len(longestWord['value'])

sys.stdout.write(longestWord['value'])
```

it doesn't change actually the value, but appends it to longestWord as to list. How to change the string instead of appending?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.. Is that your whole code? And what's the actual output of this program?

Comment: Please post a short (which you did) and complete (which you didn't) program that exhibits the problem(s) you're describing, such that anyone that wants to help you have some actually executing code to look at, execute, debug, etc.

Comment: yes, it was a problem with input separator, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with what you have, but it could be reduced to a single line:

```
print(max(words, key=len))
```

If you want to keep that dict structure then:

```
longest = max(words, key=len)
longestWord = {'value': longest, 'len': len(longest)}
```

Comment: Thanks for such short approach, i'm beginner to Python and didn't tried built-in algorithms yet.